# jquery datatables using jumpToData() getting undefined error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use the page.jumpToData() api plugin with datatables v 1.10

I have included the script of the function within my page and have tried to use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

    var table = $('.datatable').dataTable();

    table.page.jumpToData( "test", 0 );

});
```

I've omitted a number of settings for simplicity

The api script is:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('page.jumpToData()', function (data, column) {
var pos = this.column(column, {order: 'current'}).data().indexOf(data);

if (pos >= 0) {
    var page = Math.floor(pos / this.page.info().length);
    this.page(page).draw(false);
}

return this;
});
```

I have tried placing within an InitComplete callback but no difference.

The error I get is:

```
Cannot read property 'jumpToData' of undefined
```

Which I assume means the function does not exist? I'm not sure how to resolve. Does it fail if trying to extend the api if the datatable has not fully loaded?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem for the undefined error.

I have initiated using `dataTable` instead of `DataTable`. So I was trying to access the API from a Jquery object

Having just upgraded from 1.9 to 1.10 I hadn't recognised that part!